# Automatic page break up of table with tabu

Tags: tables, tabu

I have a table with tabu. I have two questions:

- how do I make tabu break the table when the page is over and start on the next page?
- how do I fix the size of the columns? The first should be short, the second a bit broader and the last should fit the rest of the columnwidth.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \caption{Minibeispiel}
            \[\tabulinesep=10pt
            \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {XXX}
            \hline
            Short & Long & Explanation\\
            \hline
            SMS & Small Message Service & \blindtext[10]\\
            DPD & Data Package Data & \begin{itemize}
            \item Please
            \item Help
            \item Me
            \end{itemize}
            \hline
            \end{tabu}
            \]
    \end{minipage}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put a tabular in two boxes (resizebox and minipage) and additionally in a table environment nothing will ever be able to break. Beside this: before continuing to use tabu read the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/

Comment: I'd suggest to use `longtable` of `xltabular` instead of `tabu`.

Comment: Will the contents of the first and second column also contain linebreaks?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to be asking two questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Please see if one of the following examples suits your needs:

In all of the following example, I have used `xltabular` instead of `tabu`. In order to enable pagebreaks within the table, I have removed `\begin{table}[H]`, `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}`, `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` and `\[` around the original table. I have also used `\endhead` in order to repeat the column headers on the second and (following) pages.

In the first example, I have used two `l` type columns for the first two columns:

[image]

In the second example, I have used an `l` type column for the first and a fixed width  `p` type column for the second column:

[image]

In the last example, I have rotated thetable to landscape orientation. This can be useful and save space if the text in the third column is especially long:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
            \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{llX}
            \caption{Minibeispiel}\\
            \toprule
            Short & Long & Explanation\\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead
            \toprule
            Short & Long & Explanation\\
            \midrule
            \endhead
            \bottomrule
            \endfoot
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            DPD & Data Package Data & \begin{itemize}
            \item Please
            \item Help
            \item Me
            \end{itemize}\\
            \end{xltabular}

\newpage

            \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}X}
            \caption{Minibeispiel}\\
            \toprule
            Short & Long & Explanation\\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead
            \toprule
            Short & Long & Explanation\\
            \midrule
            \endhead
            \bottomrule
            \endfoot
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            DPD & Data Package Data & \begin{itemize}
            \item Please
            \item Help
            \item Me
            \end{itemize}\\
            \end{xltabular}

\begin{landscape}
            \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}X}
            \caption{Minibeispiel}\\
            \toprule
            Short & Long & Explanation\\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead
            \toprule
            Short & Long & Explanation\\
            \midrule
            \endhead
            \bottomrule
            \endfoot
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            SMS & Small Message Service & \lipsum[4]\\
            DPD & Data Package Data & \begin{itemize}
            \item Please
            \item Help
            \item Me
            \end{itemize}\\
            \end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```